# Find Duplicate characters in String ( Solution must be less than O(n^2)

Tags: arrays, string

If we traverse the string array for every character and compare with all others,we would find duplicates,but that is O(n^2)

I need some idea to do it in less than O(n^2)

Lets say input string is: nice book, then 
output will be: o

Comment: The requirement is slightly unclear. Can you provide some sample input and the result you're trying to get?

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over all characters and store them into a `HashMap` with key is the character itself and value is nay thing (the character, true, integer,..). Before adding the character to the hash map check if it already exists, if exists then it is a duplicate if not insert it

Here is a pesudo code

```
for character char in String
    if charactersMap.get(char) == null
        charactersMap.put(char, char)
    else
        print C
```

This solution is `O(n)` as it iterates over the characters once and looking up for a key into a map takes constant time.